# Eclipse RCP - Path must include project and resource name

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am using Eclipse RCP and to create editor I need this code:

```
  new Path("c:/myfile.txt")
```

I got the following problem:

```
 Path must include project and resource name
```

I don't know what the project or resource name is (I dont care about them - I want open that file). I am surprised how so simple thing (and many many other) can be so complicated in Eclipse RCP.

Comment: How are you using the `Path`? It sounds like you are probably using an Eclipse API which requires a resource in the workspace.

Comment: I have an action, where I am trying to create Editor (in Swing question of minutes, in Eclipse RCP it seems very complex): PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(file.getName());

Comment: What is `EclipseUtils`?

Comment: It contains the following static function: public static IFileEditorInput getFileEditorInput(IPath path){
  IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
  IFile file = root.getFile(path);
  if(file == null) return null;
  IFileEditorInput fileEditorInput = new FileEditorInput(file);
  return fileEditorInput;
 }

Answer (score 0):

The code

```java
IFile file = root.getFile(path);
```

requires that the path specified is in the Eclipse workspace which is why you get this error since all workspace files are in a project.

If you want an editor to access a file that is not in the workspace you will have to use an editor input implementing `IURIEditorInput` - probably `FileStoreEditorInput`:

```java
IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getStore(file.toURI());
IURIEditorInput input = new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore);
```

some editors may not understand this type of input.